# A difficult integral $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{t-s-\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\frac{1}{X}\ln\frac{1-X}{1+X} $

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Can anyone give any hints on how to rewrite this in terms of dilogarithms?

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\rm d}t \over t}\,{1 \over t - s - {\rm i}\epsilon}\,
{1 \over \,\sqrt{\, 1 - a/t\,}\,}\,
\ln\left(1 - \,\sqrt{\,1 - a/t\,}\, \over 1 + \,\sqrt{\, 1 - a/t\,}\,\right)\,,
$$
with $\epsilon$ small.

It looks horrible and I really don't know how to proceed, I have tried many variable substitutions, separate $t$ and $t - s$ via partial fractions etc...nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: So I have split the integral up in the following way, can someone comment my logic and mistakes:

Since $1-a/t$ is negative for $t<a$ we let 
$$ (1-a/t)^{1/2} = \mathrm{i}\sqrt{a/t-1}$$ in this interval, in the rest of the integration range it the usual square root. Then one can write the integral as

$$ I = \int_0^a \mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{t-s-\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\frac{1}{\mathrm{i}\sqrt{a/t-1}} \ln\frac{1-\mathrm{i}\sqrt{a/t-1}}{1+\mathrm{i}\sqrt{a/t-1}}\\[3mm]+\int_a^\infty \mathrm{d}t\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{t-s-\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a/t}} \ln\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a/t}}{1+\sqrt{1-a/t}}$$
Now substituting $u=1-a/t$ and $u=a/t-1$ we get 
$$I=-\mathrm{i}\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}u\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{1}{a-s(1+u)-\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\ln\frac{1-\sqrt{u}}{1+\sqrt{u}}\\[3mm]+\int_0^1\mathrm{d}u\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{1}{a-s(1-u)-\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\ln\frac{1-\sqrt{u}}{1+\sqrt{u}}$$
Now there is an obvious substitution $u=v^2$ but I how would I treat the first log since the stuff inside its parenthesis becomes negative for $u>1$ and I rather not mess with absolute value bars (e.g. in $\log z = \log|z|+\mathrm{i}\arg z$). Is there any other way from here on?

Comment: What is $m$ and $s$ and how is this well-defined? $1-\tfrac{4m^2}{t} ≤ 0 ⇔ t ≤ 4m^2$, which happens fors some time of positive measure if $m$ is nonzero and you integrate over $0 .. ∞$. (Also you get problems for $t = 0$, $t = s$, $t = 4m²$ and $m = 0$, but these are isolated points and may be ignored.)

Comment: I don't understand your first question?

Comment: Do you mean how is $\sqrt{-1}$ defined?

Comment: Is this an exercise? Who in the world would need to solve this integral?

Comment: It's not a textbook integral Gustavo. This is how integrals of the real world look like unfortunately.

Comment: And integrals in the real world only rarely come out in terms of dilogarithm.

Comment: Why do you think this integral can be written as a dilogarithm?

Comment: Please, make the title more informative.

Comment: @Mauchy can you tell me the motivation for this integral?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy WolframAlpha is can actually churn out an antiderivative for this integral in terms of dilogarithms plus elementary functions, though it is nauseatingly long.

Comment: @DavidH I see, thank you.